# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryRepository':

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryRepository': Error creating bean with name 'categoryRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.CategoryRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Category

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private @NotNull String categoryName;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String imageUrl;


    public Category() {
    }
    public Category(@NotNull String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Category(@NotNull String categoryName, String description) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Category(@NotNull String categoryName, String description, String imageUrl) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return this.categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User {category id=" + id + ", category name='" + categoryName + "', description='" + description + "'}";
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.service.CategoryService;
import com.example.demo.common.ApiResponse;
import com.example.demo.model.Category;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("category")
public class CategoryController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> storeCategory(@Valid @RequestBody Category category) {
        categoryService.saveCategory(category);
        
        ArrayList<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
        message.add("Category is added successfully");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(new ApiResponse(true, message), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Category;
import com.example.demo.repository.CategoryRepository;
@Service
public class CategoryService {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public void saveCategory(Category category) {
        // categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Category;
@Repository("categoryRepository")
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    Category findByCategoryName(String categoryName);
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.model.*" })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

how to solve this error?

I ran the program but it showed this error.

Comment: Where is your `@SpringBootApplication` defined? You're probably missing some `@ComponentScan` or `@EntityScan` or some configuration.

Comment: `@Repository` is not necessary. Though the error indicates that you are not scanning base packages for entity classes in the classpath

Comment: Please add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. Also specify which Spring Boot version you are using (you might even want to add your `pom.xml` so we can see your dependencies). Finally please add the **full stacktrace** instead of a snippet.

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.model.*" })`  is not valid, use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.model" })`

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this tag @EnableJpaRepositories in your MainApplication class and @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
"your entities package.*"
}

Comment: where to put @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "your entities package.*" }?

Comment: what examples for what I can put in basePackages ?

Comment: You shouldn't do this as this should be enabled by default.

Comment: now the endpoint doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).